# Symlog scale for Bokeh plots

Tags: python, bokeh

I have great plots using matplotlib for which I use `symlog` for both `xscale` and `yscale`. I was wondering how to build a similar scale for **Bokeh**. For now, I can only find `log` scale in **Bokeh** but given I have negative values, it doesn't give a good result...

Has someone a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh `2.1.1` there is not a good answer. There is no "symlog" capability built in, and although Bokeh is general extensible through custom extensions, unfortunately scale mappers are the one part of Bokeh that are *not* easily extensible yet. I'd encourage you to make a feature request on the [project issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) and if you have the time and ability we would certainly be all to happy to help you work on a PR for the feature as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess it's solved then ;). Would be a great thing indeed!